# Get repeated regex matches

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I have a string, example

```
my $str = "Dave birthday on 11/12/68 Fred enjoys cooking Wilma likes cake"
```

I have some strings I want to match their name AND the text up until the next match, so I am currently trying

```
my $re = "(Dave|Sally|Fred|John|Wilma)" # created dynamically
```

I can do repeated matches like

```
my @matches;
push @matches, [$1, $2] while $str =~ /$re/g;
warn Dumper @matches;
```

Not sure what I would put in to pull out $2

This will grab matches, but I am trying to find a way to match also the part inbetween up to the next match, so ideally I would end up with something like (don't care if its an array, hash or whatever).

```
[["Dave"," birthday on 11/12/68"],
 ["Fred"," enjoys cooking"],
 ["Wilma"," likes cake"]]
```

I can probably do this by splitting strings on matching positions and remainder, but I was wondering if there was any obvious regex way I was missing ?

Comment: I would split on the names like so `my (undef, @foo) = split /$re/, $str;` and get rid of the first empty string (from the LHS of _Dave_).

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, is there a way to push the matching names along with that method at all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a look-ahead assertion so that the next search starts before the name that ended the previous search.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $str = 'Dave birthday on 11/12/68 Fred enjoys cooking Wilma likes cake';
my $names_re  = qr/Dave|Sally|Fred|John|Wilma/;
my $re = qr/($names_re) (.*?)(?= $names_re|$)/;

my @matches;
push @matches, [ $1, $2 ] while $str =~ /$re/g;

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@matches;
```

Comment: If your Perl is at least 5.22 you can also use the `/n` modifier locally so you don't need to get rid of the group around the names in the original `$re` from the question like this: `while $str =~ /$re(.*?)(?n:(?=$re|$))/g`. It will turn off the capturing inside of the look-ahead. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#*n*

Answer (score 1):

Using `split` with a capture group to produce a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $str = 'Dave birthday on 11/12/68 Fred enjoys cooking Wilma likes cake';
my $names_re = qr/(Dave|Sally|Fred|John|Wilma)/;

my @parts = split /\s*\b$names_re\b\s*/, $str;
shift @parts;
my %result = @parts;

print Dumper \%result;
```

Comment: I like this answer, feels slightly easier for my mind to follow. Not sure if there are any pros and cons compared to the look-ahead answer, but will give them both some testing. Many thanks.